# Updating checkbox with a custom button

Tags: custom-button

I am trying to have a custom button that will update a checkbox from false to true by clicking the custom button.  I am trying to get the code to work and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: +1 Mihai. @Samuel its hard for us to help without seeing the code you are claiming isn't working.

Comment: note this can be done on standard detail pages with onclick javascript buttons and there are plenty of examples locatable via search engines

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use a javascript button.  Here is some sample code on the Account object where the name of the field is "Checkbox__c":

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}

     if({!Account.Checkbox__c} == false)
     {
          var c = new sforce.SObject("Account");
          c.id = "{!Account.Id}";
          c.Checkbox__c = true;
          result = sforce.connection.update([c]);
          if ( result[0].getBoolean( "success" ) )
          {
               window.location.reload();
          }
          else
          {
               alert( result[0].errors.message);
          }
     }
     else
     {
          alert("Already True");
     }
```